# Knee position while on the aero bar

Tags: road-bike, handlebars, saddle, ergonomics, triathlon

I find that my knees are coming ahead of the pedals while I am on the aero bars. I am not sure whether this is right or wrong.
In the below image, I don't feel pain on my lower back for a long duration but I am seated on the edge of the saddle. This results in a painful pelvic girdle. But I am worried that my knee is too far ahead of the pedal on the horizontal crank arm position.

[image]

In the below image, I am seated on the middle of the saddle which brings my knee a little closer to the pedal. But I experience lower back pain after a very short time.

[image]

I am afraid, both the positions are wrong because both the positions bring my knee in front of the pedal.

[image: spacer ring removed from top and placed below.]

Now my question is, where should my knee be with respect to the pedal or toes?
Also how to correct it (if wrong), should I reduce the stem length or bring my saddle forward? Invite other suggestions as well!
Currently the stem length is 100 mm.

Comment: A seatpost with a specific triathlon clamp will move the saddle forward (and tilt the nose down, which is often done).

Comment: @Carel If I move my seat forward, I am afraid my knees will come way forward with respect to the pedals.

Comment: I'm not a triathlete: I'm not giving advice on this. My observation is that specialist tri bikes have steeper seat tubes than this bike. That steeper angle would move the seat forward, so many triathletes would have a similar position. Have you had a pro tri-bike fitting?

Comment: Go to Google Images and type "cyclists".

Comment: That thing about the knee having to be directly over the pedal? It's a myth. Based on the photos and your description, I think you just need to move your seat forward.

Comment: @andy256 I haven't had a bike fit yet. I am trying to do that myself. Bike fit is too costly for me in India. I can't afford that.

Comment: It's hard to tell from these photos so take these as comments and questions rather than an answer -- but it seems like that frame may be a bit big for you. Putting aero bars on a road bike isn't ideal -- if you're doing draft-legal you may want to investigate ITU-legal mini-aero bars. Where is the tip of the saddle in comparison to the BB? I'm not a big fan of KOPS or related fitting systems but if you are, then when you drop a plumb line the bike has to be horizontal, and it appears that your bike is being held in the rear on a trainer but the front wheel is on the floor.

Comment: Added a new photo with front wheel in level to back wheel. Also removed spacer ring from top and placed it below.

Comment: You're sitting on the saddle-nose, move the thing forward. Putting that spacer under the stem works against the aero-position, same as flipping the stem. The idea with the aero-position is to have the stem as low as possible to get your spine flat, straight and level. Here you might end up with an aching back.

Answer (score 4):

Proper fit in an aerobar posture is designed to allow you to race well. In order to race well you will need to be comfortable enough to produce power, to reduce aerodynamic drag, and to handle the bike well and safely for the duration of your race. **If your fit otherwise meets all your needs**, you shouldn't be concerned about where your knee is positioned relative to the pedal. Under UCI regulations (see section 2 of chapter 3 [here](http://www.uci.ch/mm/Document/News/Rulesandregulation/16/80/73/1-GEN-20150313-E_English.pdf)), the nose of the saddle should be a minimum of 5 cm behind a vertical line through the bottom bracket; morphological exemptions can be made to bring the nose of the saddle up to the bottom bracket. Some riders do not compete under UCI rules and the saddle can be forward of that; and many time triallists will sit only on the front half of their saddles, effectively bringing them even farther forward. The forwardmost position of the pedal will be determined by the bottom bracket and the crank length. Some riders use "short" cranks to improve their aerodynamic position, and that will also change the position of the knee relative to the pedal. The location of the cleat and the length of your foot will also determine where your knee is positioned relative to your toes.

Optimize your fit to achieve your other goals. Don't focus solely on where your knee is positioned.